# OR between two function call

Tags: algorithm

What is the meaning of a || between two function call 
like

```
{
//some code 
return Find(n.left,req)||Find(n.right,req);
}
```

http://www.careercup.com/question?id=7560692

can some one help me to understand . Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't really a question about an *algorithm* - it's a question about an *operator* in a language, and you haven't said what the language is. Work out what language you're interested in, and then look up the meaning in the relevant language specification. (It's almost certainly the conditional OR operator, but you should look it up for yourself.)

Comment: Thanks , consider me not an expert but a new programmer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java (and C and C#) || means "lazy or". The single stroke | also means "or", but operates slightly differently.

To calculate a||b, the computer calculates the truth value (true or false) of a, and if a is true it returns the value true *without bothering to calculate b*, hence the word "lazy". Only if a is false, will it checks b to see if it is true (and so if a or b is true).

To calculate a|b, the computer works out the value of a and b first, then "ors" the answers together.

The "lazy or" || is more efficient, because it sometimes does not need to calculate b at all. The only reason you might want to use a|b is if b is actually a function (method)  call, and because of some side-effect of the method you want to be sure it executes exactly once. I personally consider this poor programming technique, and on the very few occasions that I want b to always be explicitly calculated I do this explicitly and then use a lazy or.

Eg consider a function or method foo() which returns a boolean. Instead of

boolean x = a|foo(something);

I would write

boolean c=foo(something); 
boolean x = a||c;

Which explicitly calls foo() exactly once, so you know what is going on.

Much better programming practice, IMHO. Indeed the best practice would be to eliminate the side effect in foo() entirely, but sometimes that's hard to do.

If you are using lazy or || think about the order you evaluate it in. If a is easy to calculate and usually true, a||b will be more efficient than b||a, as most of the time a simple calculation for a is all that is needed. Conversely if b is usually false and is difficult to calculate, b||a will not be much more efficient than a|b. If one of a or b is a constant and the other a method call, you should have the constant as the first term a||foo() rather than foo()||a as a method call will always be slower than using a simple local variable.

Hope this helps.

Peter Webb

Answer (score 1):

It means that it returns true if one of the two functions is true (or both of them).

Depends on the programming language, the method calls Find(n.left,req) -> if it's true - returns true. if it's false, it calls Find(n.right,req) and returns its Boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

```
 return Find(n.left,req)||Find(n.right,req);
```

means execute first find **{Find(n.left,req)}** and return true if it returns true or

execute second find return the value true if it return true, otherwise false.